# Websites to share writing in French?

Tags: self-publishing, short-story, websites

I'm looking for a website to share short stories (5-20 pages), or longer stories in episodic form.

Preferably, it should either be in French or multilingual, not be focused on fanfiction and have an option to share stories by adding chapters episodically (for example, "releasing" a chapter every month and making them easy to navigate).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps these are not the most fitted options for your needs, but they are definitely worth checking out. If you are looking to publish for free there is wordpress (which you can use in either case to promote your content).

1. I have found this link, which was last updated last year, but which still points to working solutions for your problem: [Where to read or list serials](https://theonlinenovel.wordpress.com/where-to-read-or-list-serials/). Particularly promising is Amazon's Kindle program, although I must say the royalties with them are quite low.
2. You could try Patreon, where you could have your works only accessible to those who pay above a certain threshold each month. Like, say, those who pledge you $5 or more each month may read your stories.
3. You could also use Leanpub, a publishing platform that let's you publish works as 'unfinished' and then update them periodically. The great thing with this platform is that you can set a minimum of money you want, but then the reader can pay you more.